# String manipulation in matrices: a dimensional issue

Tags: string, r, matrix, multidimensional-array, exponentiation

I'm trying to define a function manipulating matrices of strings in R.

**{+,*} MATRICES MULTIPLICATION**

The {+,*}-product of two square matrices **A** and **B** of dimension n is a matrix **C** defined by the elements:  **C**<sub>i,j</sub> = Sum<sub>k=1,...,n</sub>**A**<sub>i,k</sub> * **B**<sub>k,j</sub>.

For example, consider the matrix  `M <- matrix(c(a,b,0,0,c,d,0,0,e),3,3)`.  Then M times M is  `M <- matrix(c(a^2,a*b+b*c,b*d,0,c^2,c*d+d*e,0,0,e^2),3,3)`.

**{c(,),paste0(,)} MATRICES MULTIPLICATION**

The rule of this operation I would like to implement are the same of the previous stated multiplication with the essential mutation that the sum should be a concatenation and the product should be a paste. In other words, where in the previous formula we found `a+b`, now the output should be "c(a,b)", and when we found `a*b`, now we should read this as `paste0(a,b)`.

Some of the usual properties have to be respescted, namely the distributive properties and the 0 element properties. Hence, if `a <- c("q",0,"w")` and `b <- c("e")` then `a*b <- c("qe",0,"we")` (and we should freely forget the 0 element, dropping it as it won't affect the computation.

Moreover, we are multiplying equaldimensioned matrices, hence each element  **C**<sub>i,j</sub> = Sum<sub>k=1,...,n</sub>**A**<sub>i,k</sub> * **B**<sub>k,j</sub> is now to be read as  `c("A[i,1]B[1,j]",...,"A[i,n]B[n,j]")`.

For semplicity sakeness, let's consider **B** always a *simple* matrix, meaning that each of its elements are atomic string, and not concatenation of string (the generalization is a subsequent step).

Let's give an example. Let  `A <- matrix(c("a","b",0,0,"c","d",0,0,"e"),3,3)`,  then `mult(A,A) = matrix(c("aa",c("ab","bc"),"bd",0,"cc",c("cd","de"),0,0,"ee"),3,3)`  and `mult(mult(A,A),A) = matrix(c("aaa",c("aab","abc","bcc"),c("abd","bcd","bde"),0,"ccc",c("ccd","cde","dee"),0,0,"eee"),3,3)`.

**PARTIAL (NOT WORKING) IMPLEMENTATION**

Consider as input a couple of nxn matrices **M** , **N** with whether 0 or array of strings c(*s*<sub>1</sub>,*s*<sub>2</sub>,...) as **i,j** elements.  As output I would like to have a matrix **MN = M x N** where the multiplication is defined in analogy with the symbolic multiplication:

**MN**<sub>i,j</sub> = 0 if **M**<sub>i,.</sub> or **N**<sub>.,j</sub> is 0
**MN**<sub>i,j</sub> = paste(**M**<sub>i,.</sub>,**N**<sub>.,j</sub>) otherwise (using the *distributive* property of `paste()`)

I gave a (wrong, does not check properly the zeros) definition of the base *row/column paste* function as

```
MijPaste <- function(Row,Col){
  if(Col[1]=="0"){
    Mij <- 0
  } else if(Row[1]=="0"){
      Mij <- 0
    } else
      Mij <- paste(Row,Col,sep="")
  return(Mij)
}
```

I've not been able to go from this step to a proper definition of the multiplication function, as the element Mij that I would like to insert inside the matrix are not of the right dimension. And hence I get a `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error. My current implementation is:

```
# define the dimension of the matrix, here for example 3
dim <- 3
# define the Multiplication function as an iteration of the MijPaste function
Mult <- function(M1,M2){
    #allocate a matrix of dimension nxn
    M <-  matrix(0,dim,dim)
    #for each element i,j define it as the MijPaste of row i column j
      for(i in 1:dim){
      for(j in 1:dim){
        stringi <- M1[i,]
        stringj <- M2[,j]
        M[i,j] <- MijPaste(stringi,stringj)
      }
    }
  return(M)
}
```

The code doesn't work. I could probably change the matrix into a multidimensional array, but I would like the output to be usable as a matrix for further multiplication (for example to defin (MxN)xC).

How can I do?

Thank you!

P.S. You can test the code using a simple example matrix

```
Matr <- matrix(c("11","12","13","21","22","23","31","32","33"),dim,dim)
```

and running

```
Mult(Matr,Matr)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't have a vector (of length >= 2) within a matrix "slot", i.e., you can't assign `c("A[i,1]B[1,j]",...,"A[i,n]B[n,j]")` to `M[i,j]`. You have to *collapse* this vector to a length-one character string first, as I pointed out in my comments below.

Comment: Ok, that makes your point. Then, I'll probably have to collapse it to a lenght-one string, using some delimiting character, and break it up again before doing the multiplication. Hope that's feasibile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste` directly with the matrices, if you set the dimensions manually:

```
MN <- matrix(paste(M, N, sep=""), nrow=nrow(M), ncol=ncol(M))
```

Now filter the zeros and replace:

```
MN[(M==0) | (N==0)] <- 0
```

EDIT: the pointwise product shown above is NOT what the OP wants.

As I said in the comment, you can fix your function adding `collapse=""` to your first function. I get the following results:

```
> M <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9],3,3)
> N <- matrix(LETTERS[10:18],3,3)

> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "D"  "G" 
[2,] "B"  "E"  "H" 
[3,] "C"  "F"  "I" 
> N
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "J"  "M"  "P" 
[2,] "K"  "N"  "Q" 
[3,] "L"  "O"  "R" 

> Mult(M,N)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "AJDKGL" "AMDNGO" "APDQGR"
[2,] "BJEKHL" "BMENHO" "BPEQHR"
[3,] "CJFKIL" "CMFNIO" "CPFQIR"
```

As you can see, your function matches the elements in matrices `M` and `N` *before* pasting.

If you want to keep the elements of each matrix together, you can use these two lines:

```
> coll <- function(x)paste(x,collapse="")
> outer(apply(M,1,coll),apply(N,2,coll),paste0)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "ADGJKL" "ADGMNO" "ADGPQR"
[2,] "BEHJKL" "BEHMNO" "BEHPQR"
[3,] "CFIJKL" "CFIMNO" "CFIPQR"
```

Of course, you have to insert the zeros manually after this.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I fear that the past function gives as output a pointwise "product" and cannot be forced (as builtin) to give row by column "product", which is the desired output.

Comment: In that case, all you have to do is add `collapse=""` in your call to `paste`. i.e., like this: `paste(Row,Col,sep="",collapse="")`

Comment: Also, in your function, you only check if the first element of `Row` and `Col` is zero to return zero. That seems odd. What exactly do you want? M[i,j] should be zero if *any* element in `Row`/`Col` is zero or only if *all* of them are zero?

Comment: Yep, you'r totally right. The check was not correct. I think that the best way of explaining what I want is in term of a (+,*) arithmetic where a*b is paste (a,b) and a+b is c(a,b) and the operation works with the usual properties for 0. I'll make this more clear for everybody in the main problem, giving a better example.

Comment: @gvdr, I'll be waiting! :-)

Comment: Nope. See my comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
pmat <- function(m1, m2) matrix(
          ifelse(m1=="0"|m2=="0", "0", paste0(m1,m2) ) ,
                            dim(m1)[1], dim(m1)[2] )


> pmat(Matr, Matr)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "1111" "2121" "3131"
[2,] "1212" "2222" "3232"
[3,] "1313" "2323" "3333"
```

I couldn't tell whether you were ready for the dimensional multiplication or not. If you expect N elements per index then you want the `kronecker` function, which will require a slightly different function:

## Insert:

Maybe you should have posted a better test case? Then you could have been more explicit about what you wanted. This shows how `kronecker`-applied `pmat` rearranged as an array will give you MN[1,1] as the 1st column of the first matrix:

```
 M <- matrix(c("a1","b1","c1","0"),2,2)
 N <- matrix(c("c2","d2","e2","f2"),2,2)
 MN <- array( kmat,c( 2,2,4))
 MN[ , 1,1]
#[1] "a1c2" "a1d2"
```

---

```
> pmat <- function(m1, m2) matrix( ifelse(m1=="0"|m2=="0", "0", paste0(m1,m2) )  )
> kronecker(Matr, Matr, pmat)
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  
 [1,] "1111" "1121" "1131" "2111" "2121" "2131" "3111" "3121" "3131"
 [2,] "1112" "1122" "1132" "2112" "2122" "2132" "3112" "3122" "3132"
 [3,] "1113" "1123" "1133" "2113" "2123" "2133" "3113" "3123" "3133"
 [4,] "1211" "1221" "1231" "2211" "2221" "2231" "3211" "3221" "3231"
 [5,] "1212" "1222" "1232" "2212" "2222" "2232" "3212" "3222" "3232"
 [6,] "1213" "1223" "1233" "2213" "2223" "2233" "3213" "3223" "3233"
 [7,] "1311" "1321" "1331" "2311" "2321" "2331" "3311" "3321" "3331"
 [8,] "1312" "1322" "1332" "2312" "2322" "2332" "3312" "3322" "3332"
 [9,] "1313" "1323" "1333" "2313" "2323" "2333" "3313" "3323" "3333"
```

Comment: I'm not ready for dimensional multiplication in the final matrix output, but I don't have any problem going through a dimensional multiplication to retrieve the output.

Comment: The problem here is that in my **MN** [1,1] position I would like to have a **M** [1,.] row by **N** [.,1] column "product", not a pointwise product. If, for exemple, the first row of **M** is `c("a","b")` and the first of column of **N** is `c("c","d")` the output in **MN** [1,1] should be `c("ac","bd")`.

Comment: That's much useful, but still not what I wanted. Consider the matrix `M <- matrix(c("a","b",0,0,"c","d",0,0,"e"),3,3)`. If I'm using the kroenecker function right, if I compute M times M the outcome is `matrix(c("aa","bb",0,0,"cc","dd",0,0,"ee"),3,3)` while the desired output, in analogy with the usual matrix multiplication `%*%`, should be `matrix(c("aa",c("ab","bc"),0,0,"cc","cd+de",0,0,"ee"),3,3)` (or, using the common (+,*) arithmetics, `matrix(c(a^2,ab+bc,0,0,c^2,cd+de,0,0,e^2),3,3)`). I'm sorry for not having been more clear before.